# How to migrate from .net 5 to .net 6?

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-6.0

I am making my first migration to .Net 6 with Visual Studio 2022.  I am beginning with a .Net 5 dll project I did many months ago who compiles ok with Visual Studio 2019.  I opened the same solution with Visual Studio 2022 and all I did is I switched the target from .Net 5 to .Net 6.  I thought this will be this easy.  I was wrong.

When I compiled, I had those errors :

```
NU1202  Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 does not support any target frameworks.   

NU1202  Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / win10-arm64. Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 does not support any target frameworks. HessBay.Framework

NU1202  Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 does not support any target frameworks.   

NU1202  Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / win10-x86. Package Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.6 does not support any target frameworks.
```

As those are the latest versions, I created a new .net 6 library project to see what it uses.  There was none...  So, I removed these nugets.

I now have many errors who offers to insert a "using System.Windows.Media", but this does not insert nothing.

[image: Suggestion to correct the SolidColorBrush missing type]

So, I manually added the suggested using instruction, but the error stays.  Probably because I have no reference to PresentationCore but I find no way to add this reference and I am unable to find any Nuget who would replace it.  I have a similar problem with IValueConverter.

I think the base of my problem is the fact I don't understand what implies .net 6 and this is probably my first issue of many many others to come.  So, what I am asking is : Can you refer me to a guide who could help me understand what I need to do?  All I find [refer to ASP.NET Core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and talk about web changes.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/update-existing-projects-to-the-latest-release

Comment: The project dependency you took on was hard coded to .NET 5 with a Windows SDK version, https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences/0.8.6 So before Microsoft publishes a new version with .NET 6 support, you'd better stay on .NET 5.

Comment: @juharr, I don't have a wapproj file (what is that?), only a csproj.  I did remove the projectReunion nugets and added the Microsoft.WindowsAppSdk but it changes nothing.  The brand new test project (dll with .net6) don't have this nuget.  I am so confused with those maui, WinUI3, reunion, .net6 changes, I don't know where I am anymore.